# checking if for any image file (.JPG) in folder "A" there is an annotation file (.XML) in folder "B"

Tags: python, object-detection, tensorflow-datasets

I have a very big datasets of images and their annotations saved in two separate folders, however not all images have an annotation file.
How can I write a python code to check my image files (.JPG) in folder "A"  and **delete** the image if there is not an annotation file (.xml) with the same name for that specific image, and **do nothing** if annotation file exists?

I have written the following code following @Gabip comment below:
[image]

How can I improve this code?

Comment: I have written the following code:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
from os import listdir,remove
from os.path import isfile, join

images_path = "full/path/to/folder_a"
annotations_path = "full/path/to/folder_b"


# this function will help to retrieve all files with provided extension in a given folder
def get_files_names_with_extension(full_path, ext):
    return [f for f in listdir(full_path) if isfile(join(full_path, f)) and f.lower().endswith(".{}".format(ext))]


images = get_files_names_with_extension(images_path, "jpg")
annotations = set([f.split(".")[0] for f in get_files_names_with_extension(annotations_path, "xml")])

for img in images:
    if img.split(".")[0] not in annotations:
        remove(join(images_path, img))
```

Comment: Looks good, although, I'd convert the annotations to a set to make the lookup constant instead of bounded by number of files in the annotation dir

Comment: which python do you use?

Comment: I've updated the solution in case you use python2.7

Comment: @Gabip Dear Gabip, I ran it again with python2.7. It didn't show any error anymore, but did not remove any image from the images' folder.

Comment: I changed the code to be case insensitive to the files extensions (previously worked only if the extensions were uppercase as you asked). Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.
I made some adaptations to your suggestion.
Now:

- the number of IMAGEs and XMLs is displayed
- images are compared with XMLs
- XMLs are compared with images
- instead of erasing inconsistencies, lists are actually created with the names of the missing files

CHECK: (IMGs x XMLs) and (XMLs x IMGs)

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

images_path = "full/path/to/folder_a"
annotations_path = "full/path/to/folder_b"


# function created to return a list of all files in the "full_path" directory with an "ext" extensiondef get_files_names_with_extension(full_path, ext):
    return [f for f in listdir(full_path) if isfile(join(full_path, f)) and f.lower().endswith(".{}".format(ext))]

# use the function to retrieve the NAME of IMGs and XMLs WITHOUT EXTENSION (facilitates the conference)images = set([f.split(".")[0] for f in get_files_names_with_extension(images_path, "jpg")])
annotations = set([f.split(".")[0] for f in get_files_names_with_extension(annotations_path, "xml")])
print('='*30)
print(f'number of IMGs = {len(images)}')
print(f'number of XMLs = {len(annotations)}')

# create a list of all IMGs looking for the one that does not have the corresponding XML
print('='*30)
list_error_img = []
for img in images:
    if img not in annotations:
        list_error_img.append(img)
if not list_error_img:
    print("OK, all IMG has its XML")        
else:
    print("ERROR: IMGs that do not have XML")
    print(list_error_img)

# creates a list of all XMLs looking for what does not have the corresponding IMG
print('='*30)
list_error_xml = []
for ann in annotations:
    if ann not in images:
        list_error_xml.append(ann)
if not list_error_xml:
    print("OK, all XML has its IMG")        
else:
    print("ERRO: XMLs tha do not have IMG")
    print(list_error_xml)
print('='*30)
```